# Why inner div is not taking 100% of parent div?

Tags: html, css, layout

The example below demos this weird behaviour: the *outer* div has a set size and I want the *inner* div to take 100% of this size (i.e. the end result should be just an inner red block fully covering the outer blue block).

I have set the height of the *inner* div to 100% but its height is still 0px, however, the 100% width that I set is working correctly, it computes to 300px, which is 100% of its parent div).

First, why is the 100% height not working? Second, how to make the 100% height to work?

```css
.full {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.outer {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 300px;
}

.inner {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: add display:grid to outer OR remove height:100% and add display:flex to outer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bug when parent height is determined by min-height/max-height children with percentage heights are sized incorrectly.

Just use some other method to assign the height, may be  fixed or by using flex or whatever. In following example I added `display:flex;` to parent and `flex: 1;` to child:

```css
.full {
  background: yellow;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.outer {
  background: blue;
  min-height: 100px;
  min-width: 300px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.inner {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  flex:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="full">
  <div class="outer">
    <div class="inner"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Note:**

1. The flex property is a shorthand property for: flex-grow, flex-shrink, flex-basis. And setting `flex: 1;` actually assigns flex-grow 1, flex-basis 0.
2. Since flex-direction is row by default, and since we are using flex: 1 in child elements and we need it to grow vertically (by column direction). We have to assign `flex-direction: column;`

Comment: Thats cool. Why flex-direction: column is needed?

Comment: @user1589188 Because flex-direction is row by default, and since we are using flex: 1 in child elements, we need it to grow vertically (by column direction) .

Answer (score 1):

Try `flex-grow: 1` on inner `<div>`.